# Python - download local file

Tags: python, urllib

a python cgi script lets me search a sqlite db and presents me a link to a file for download. The files are all local files in a directory outside the web dir.
I've tried a start with:

```
 if os.access(filepath, os.R_OK):
```

This already threw me an error args = 13, Permission denied.

Next I was thinking how I should proceed:

> file_to_open = "file://" + file_to_download
>
> urllib.urlopen(file_to_open)

Unfortunately I have to deal with the error first.
As I've tested a few things:

- File is present, otherwise I receive an other error
- chmod 777 chown
- file and dir to apache's running user

I'm stuck and not sure if and how to let Python download a file outside the webroot.

Answer (score 0):

If a file should be accessible via a web application, it has to be readable by the apache user.  That's by design—anything not readable by the apache user is not accessible from the web.

Since you probably won't want to `chown` these files to the apache user (which would potentially allow web users to modify them), you have basically two options:

- Set the group of the files to the apache user's group (using `chgrp`) and make them readable by any user of that group (`chmod g+r FILE...`), or
- make the files readable to any process on the server (`chmod o+r FILE...`).

Make sure the apache user has at least execute (`+x`) rights on all parent directories of the files or this will not work.

You could also use a separate service to provide these files to the web application, but this is significantly more complicated (and you probably won't need it).